# Parent/child click relationships in AngularJS directives

Tags: angularjs-directive, kendo-treeview

I have a custom directive placed on a Kendo UI treeview widget.

It seems to be working fine side-by-side, except that I'm trying to simply display the custom icons next to the tree node which is clicked on (see sample image below).

So my directive is `data-toggle-me`, placed next to the Kendo `k-template` directive as follows :

```html
<div class="reports-tree" kendo-tree-view="nav.treeview"             
                    k-options="nav.treeOptions"
                    k-data-source="nav.reportsTreeDataSource"
                    k-on-change="nav.onTreeSelect(dataItem)"  >

      <span class="tree-node" k-template data-toggle-tree-icons>{{dataItem.text}}</span>
  
</div>
```

and the directive code here inserts some custom icons next to the tree node when a user `clicks` on that tree node :

```js
 .directive('toggleMe', function ($compile) {
      // Kendo treeview, use the k-template directive to embed a span.
      // Icons appear on Click event. 
      return {
          restrict: 'AE',
          transclude: true,
          template: '<span ng-show="nav.displayIcons" id="myIcons" class="reptIcons" style="display:none;width:50px;align:right;">' +
                ' <a title="add new folder" ng-click="nav.addAfter(nav.selectedItem)"><i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;' +
                '<a title="add report here" ng-click="nav.addBelow(nav.selectedItem)"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;' +
                '<a title="remove" ng-click="nav.remove(nav.selectedItem)"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;' +
                '<a title="rename" onclick="showRename(this);"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>' +
              '</span>',
          link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {              
              var icons = elem.find("#myIcons");
              elem.on('click', function (e) {                  
                  $('.reptIcons').css('display', 'none');
                  icons.css("display", "inline");
                  icons.css("margin-left", "5px");
              });              
          }
      }
    })
```

[image: treeview widget with embedded icons]

My biggest problem at this point is getting the icons to appear on the treenode which is clicked on. Then once the user clicks on a different node, the icons will only render again on the newly-clicked node.

This fiddle represents a partially-working example but the icons are appearing on every single treenode - [click tree item to show icons](http://jsfiddle.net/robertmazzo/7jLnhyLy/)

**** UPDATED TREE IMAGE - All child nodes now show icons (not what I want) ****

[image: UPDATED TREE IMAGE - All child nodes now show icons (not what I want)]

Comment: What do you mean by _causing the directive to fire the ORIGINAL click event again_?

Comment: well, I'm essentially trying to create a directive that wraps child elements. These child elements have their own ng-click events. For example, looking at this tag above in the `node` variable `<a title="add new folder" ng-click="nav.addAfter(nav.selectedItem)">` . It usually fires `nav.addAfter` successfully; however, it ends up also triggering the `elem.on('click'` code. I know I'm missing something in the way I'm wiring this up.

Comment: So if a user clicks `add a new folder` you want `nav.addAfter(nav.selectedItem)` to be called, but not the handler registered with `elem.on('click'`?

Comment: @zeroflagL - yes, exactly. But then the `elem.on('click'` needs to get turned back on after.

Comment: @zeroflagL - I'm trying a different method, which is using the `template` option of the directive; however, my problem now is I need to icons to appear when I click on the list item. Please see here: http://jsfiddle.net/robertmazzo/7jLnhyLy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand your issue, you should try to reduce the code to the minimum and have a snippet/jsfiddle that works.

If all you want is not trigger click events when `$scope.disableParentClick` is set to true, simply add

```
elem.on('click', function (e) {
  // Do not execute click event if disabled
  if (!$scope.disableParentClick) { return; }
  ...
});
```

Now that seems all not very angular friendly to me. You should externalize your HTML in either the `template` or `templateUrl` of your directive, potentially adding to it a `ng-if="displayTemplate"` which would only display the node when a click would set `$scope.displayTemplate = true;`

Also, instead of listening for click events this way, you should use the `ng-click` directive. Everything is doable with directives. I can give more information when you better understand your problem: I suspect you are not approaching it the right way.

**UPDATE**: if all you want is display the icons list of the clicked element, you could do it way easier. You actually don't need the `toggle-me` directive, but even if you keep it you can solve all your troubles the angular-way, which is by using `ng-click`, `ng-repeat`, etc. Please have a look at the following jsFiffle to see *one way* of doing that. There are many other ways, but really try using ng-click to avoid troubles:

http://jsfiddle.net/kau9jnoe/

Comment: thx for your response. Very simply stated, if you look at my image above, you'll see that when I click on a folder my icons appear. These icons will then have `ng-click` events on them. This is the crux of my issue in creating the best directive (in conjunction with the Kendo UI treeview widget).

Comment: my latest fiddle here, but when i click on a list item all icons appear on every list item ! I only want to show my icons on the item I click on -  http://jsfiddle.net/robertmazzo/7jLnhyLy/

Comment: @bob I've updated my answer with a fiddle that do what you want. It could still be even simpler than that, it is just to show you a better angular approach.

Comment: floribon - great idea using `<data-toggle-me ng-show="nav.selected === item">`. It actually works great, except for the fact that I have an n-deep tree widget. It means that when I click on a parent node, its leaf nodes should NOT show the icons; however the leaf are showing the icons in the case where I click and expand the parent.

Comment: floribon - I thought I needed the directive because the Kendo UI treeview widget gives me the `k-template` directive in order to dynamically insert a child element below each tree node. However, I'm thinking now that I could just insert the `<span>` of icons directly into my HTML, and avoid the directive.

Comment: @floriban - what do you thinkg about the n-level tree ? is there any other tricks I can use ? see the updated image I've embedded in the orig post.

Answer (score 1):

Events in the DOM are always bubbling up. That is a click on a link would trigger an `onclick` handler on **every** element up the hierarchy, e.g. also the `body` element. After all the click happened within `body`.

The same is true for your directive. Any click within your element triggers its event handler. To circumvent this either attach the event handler somewhere else or ignore clicks from the links.

The event object has a `target` property that tells you what element initiated the event. So you could do something like this:

```
elem.on('click', function (e) { 
 if (e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'a') return; //ignore click on links
```

Comment: Here's my latest jsfiddle, attempting to use `ng-click` in the <span> of my HTML section, which sets `nav.displayIcons` to true: http://jsfiddle.net/robertmazzo/7jLnhyLy/ - My only problem here is that ALL of my list items are now showing the icons ! I only want to show what i click on.