# Binding between parent and child relation directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have two directives in parent and child relation , each one has `link` implementation  . The `parent` set a `scope` variant - `name` , which is passed to the `child` as attribute .

The order of the links execution is  - firstly - the `child` link and then the `parent` link .

After the `parent` link finish execution it broadcast to its child , but seems the child doesn't got this `scope` changes yet  .

Here Example -

```js
var myAppModule = angular.module('myAppModule', []).
  directive('parent',function($parse){
   return {
    restrict: 'E', 
    link: function(scope) {
     scope.name = "Dan";
     console.log("parent: My name is "+scope.name);
     scope.$broadcast("ready");
    }
   }
  })
  .directive('child',function($parse){
   return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
     name: '='
    },
    link: function(scope) {
     scope.$on("ready",function () {
      console.log("child: My name is "+scope.name);
     })
    }
   }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<parent>
  <child name="name">
  </child>
 </parent>
```

it logs -

```
 parent: My name is Dan
 child: My name is undefined
```

Why the `child` didn't consider the change in `name` after the `broadcast` ? Does it because the `$digest` didn't called yet for this Angular turn ?

Comment: You are right about the digest cycle.

Answer (score 2):

First, you cannot have a `<child>` directive into the `<parent>` one like this unless you use transclusion.

Then, dealing with events (`$broadcast` and `$on`) to discuss from parent to child is not recommended, instead you could have a shared service, or even easier in this case just watch for the `name` binding to be resolved.

See how it works on this snippet:

```js
var myAppModule = angular.module('myAppModule', []).
  directive('parent',function($parse){
   return {
    restrict: 'E', 
                template: '<div>Parent: {{name}}<div ng-transclude></div></div>',
                transclude: true,
    link: function(scope) {
     scope.name = "Dan";
     console.log("parent: My name is "+scope.name);
    }
   }
  })
  .directive('child',function($parse){
   return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
     name: '='
    },
                template: '<div>Child: {{name}}</div>',
    link: function(scope) {
     scope.$watch('name', function() {
                        console.log("child: My name is "+scope.name);
                    });
    }
   }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myAppModule">
  <parent>
    <child name="name"></child>
  </parent>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm encountering something similar, except I'm dealing with some span elements that are `appended` within my directive. I'd be grateful if you could give me input - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28752567/how-to-enable-disable-click-events-in-an-angularjs-directive

Comment: _you cannot have a <child> directive into the <parent> one like this unless you use transclusion._ Of course, you can. Why shouldn't that be possible?

Comment: @zeroflagL well you're right but afaik without transclusion using `<parent>` make little sense as everything under it would not ihneritate its scope but share its parent one. However here `<parent>` doesn't have own nor isolated scope so indeed that is the same. But still, I wonder why you would use a nested element without transclusion. I may be plain wrong though.

Comment: Whether a directive is an element, an attribute or a class is just a matter of form. You would never say _without transclusion using `ngModel` make little sense as everything under it would not inheritate its scope_.

Comment: Not exactly, there is semantic involved, after all that's the point of HTML. A `<ng-model></ng-model>` alone would not make sense. A `<ng-model><input></ng-model>` would have a meaning only if the input scope inherits from the ngModel one. In other words, without transclusion, `<pa><ch></ch></pa>` would produce the same scoping and behavior as `<pa></pa><ch></ch>`. We should open a chat if you want to continue this discussion to not interfere with the question. (discussion that I find quite interesting.)